# Audio duration with node-id3

Tags: node.js, audio, metadata

How can I extract an audio duration/length with `node-id3`?

I only got `album`, `title`, `year` and `image`.

Comment: I think node-id3 is a tool to read metadata and not something dedicated to extract audio duration if that information is not already present in metadata.

Answer (score 0):

node-id3 is not returning length of audio file.

you can use ffprobe command to get the metadata of the audio file.
it works for me.

const { stdout: lengthString } = await exec("ffprobe " + audioFilePath + " 2>&1 | awk '/Duration/ { print $2 }'")

let length = lengthString.substr(3, 5)